# Compare textbox value to csv C#

Tags: c#

I am making a darts scoring program and one of the functionalities I would like to add would be all the potential finishes. I have a csv with all the darts finishes, for example if player 1 has 170 left to score the program would look through the csv and output T20,T20,BULL to a specific textbox. I have achieved this using `Powershell` on a different GUI, I have looked at quite a few similar questions but still haven't figured out a way to do this. below is my `Powershell` script (might be irrelevant)

```
$radioButton4_Click = {
    $textbox4.text = ""
    $text = $textbox2.text
    $CSV = Import-Csv "$Dartsfinishes\DartsFinishes.csv"
    ForEach($score in $CSV){
        if($score.result -like $text){
            $textbox4.text = $score.Outcome
        }Else{
  
        }
    }
}
```

This is as far as I have got from reading online. I can see similarities between both.

```
private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, string path)
        {
            string fileloc = "mypath";
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileloc);
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] columns = line.Split(',');
                foreach (string column in columns)
                {
                    if (column == textBox5.Text)
                    {
                        textBox10.Text = column;
                    }
                    
                }
            }

        }
```

This is where I am at right now, with the `Powrshell` script it identifies the columns in my csv but in `C#` it doesn't.
below is my spreadsheet and the column headers. I have also added a gif of the `Powershell` darts gui and my `C#` gui to show where I am trying to get the finishes to display.

[image]

Below is how my `Powershell` gui Works

[image]

as you can see my `C#` gui is pretty much the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your current C# code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: this is what I have so far please note new is an understatement to using C#

Comment: So you have `lines` variable which has all the lines read from the file. And you have a loop which iterates thru `lines`. You need to write code inside foreach loop. But we don't  know what you have in the file, and what logic you want to apply on `line` variable and what should be written to the textbox. You are on the right path, you need to translate the logic of the powershell script to C#. Try that and add details of the issue in the question when you face any issues.

Comment: @Chetan thank you for the reply I will try my best and I will update the question when I am a little closer

Comment: There are a number of things to think about. Firstly, you are reading the finishes file with every action - I'd suggest baking it into the code or reading it when the app starts and making it available to your checking routine. That will save a lot of disk and garbage collector activity. I'd expect your CSV to be 2 columns, e.g., "170","T20, T20, Bulleye", so think about how you can optimise your reading of the file. Compare the current score to the first column and output the second. I'd also look at pulling that functionality into a function used in the routine where you update the score.

Comment: @Lazarus wow mind blown haha, thank you for your comment. maybe the best thing is to put this project on hold and do a lot more research.